# RegEx Pattern Not Matching Sentence Terminators

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to determine the end of a sentences for a parsing app I am working on. Regex isn't really my strong suit and could use some help.

Here is an example sentence I am using (words array):

```
Hi! What's up? I know I owe you $1.50. Sorry.I swear I'll give it to
you later...
```

My code runs .Split() on a paragraph and then passes the words as an array for parsing. However, the regex doesn't seem to be detecting the values I am using to determine that a sentence has ended (".", "!", "?"). Also, some criteria not in my code - I'd like to be able to determine the difference between a period and money. And, gracefully handle a no-space end-of-sentence period.

Here is the bit of code. Can somebody advise on why the pattern isn't matching?

```
foreach (var word in words)
{
    string pat = @"(?sx-m)[^\r\n].*?(?:(?:\.|\?|!|\:)\s)";

    Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m = r.Match(word);
    while (m.Success)
        sentanceNum++;
}
```

Per Vera's comments, here is my final code block:

```
               int sentenceNum = 1;
            // Regex for sentence terminators
               string pat = @"(?:.*?([.?!:]))*";

            // Regex for money (not a sentance terminator)
            // Regex borrowed from online code example.
            string money =
                @"^\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?$";

            Regex d = new Regex(money, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match m = d.Match(word);

            // if it isn't money, increment sentanceNum. Increment 
            // will only happen if 'pat' var matches, otherwise, increment by 0.
            if (!m.Success)
                sentanceNum = sentanceNum + r.Match(word).Groups[1].Captures.Count;
```

Comment: Your pattern matches great. The only problem might be the forced `\s` at the end. If you remove it it will work. But I see a problem how you used the pattern. You've a `while` loop that checks for success. But this will never change inside the loop. You've to add `m = m.NextMatch()` inside the loop to avoid an infinite loop. If you're only interested in the number of punctuation marks you can use something like `(?:.*?([.?!:]))*` and check the number of captures of the first group by `r.Match(word).Groups[1].Captures.Count`. BTW: `(?:\.|\?|!|\:)` = `[.?!:]`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Vera. Your RegEx did the trick. Also, the match count code helped. I'd mark as answer but, since you posted as comment - just saying many thanks.

Comment: I guess we can’t always choose our input data format, so the following might be irrelevant.  In any case: I like the practice of ending sentences with two spaces.  Not because of how it looks but solely because it makes it much easier to recognize sentences with tools like regex.